# Eliminate cases based on multiple rows values

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I have a base with the following information:

***edit:*** ***each row is an individual that lives in a house, multiple individuals with a unique P_ID and AGE can live in the same house with the same H_ID, I'm looking for all the houses with all the individuals based on the condition that there's at least one person over 60 in that house, I hope that explains it better ***

```
show(base)

              H_ID           P_ID        AGE        CONACT
1      10010000001   1001000000102        35          33
2      10010000001   1001000000103        12          31
3      10010000001   1001000000104         5          NA
4      10010000001   1001000000101        37          10
5      10010000002   1001000000206         5          NA
6      10010000002   1001000000205        10          NA
7      10010000002   1001000000204        18          31
8      10010000002   1001000000207         3          NA
9      10010000002   1001000000203        24          35
10     10010000002   1001000000202        43          33
11     10010000002   1001000000201        47          10
12     10010000003   1001000000302        26          33
13     10010000003   1001000000301        29          10
14     10010000004   1001000000401        56          32
15     10010000004   1001000000403        22          31
16     10010000004   1001000000402        49          10
17     10010000005   1001000000503         1          NA
18     10010000005   1001000000501        24          10
19     10010000005   1001000000502        23          10
20     10010000006   1001000000601        44          10
21     10010000007   1001000000701        69          32
```

I want a list with all the houses and all the individuals living there based on the condition that there's at least one person 60+, here's a link for the data: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Od8zlOE3U3DO0YRGnBadFz804OUDnuQZ?usp=sharing

And here's how I made the base:

```
hogares<-read.csv("/home/servicio/Escritorio/TR_VIVIENDA01.CSV")
personas<-read.csv("/home/servicio/Escritorio/TR_PERSONA01.CSV")
datos<-merge(hogares,personas)

base<-data.frame(datos$ID_VIV, datos$ID_PERSONA, datos$EDAD, datos$CONACT)
base
```

Any help is much much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: If you are keeping id basedon at least one element AGE > 60, but why there are no IDs with that group

Comment: each row is an individual that lives in a house, multiple individuals with a unique P_ID and AGE can live in the same house with the same H_ID, I'm looking for all the houses with all the individuals based on the condition that there's at least one person over 60 in that house, I hope that explains it better

Comment: there is only row that shows AGE > 60, in the expected output, none of H_ID groups have AGE > 60

Comment: It is part of a larger data set, on those first 21 cases there is only one individual over 60, but there are a lot more

Comment: I want the houses list that include a person over 60 with all the persons that live there, including the 60+, sorry if I'm not being clear enough, I'm gonna try to put the data now on my question

Comment: sorry for the time, the data is now up and I added how i obtain those variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by:

Adding a variable with the maximum age per household

`base$maxage <- ave(base$AGE, base$H_ID, FUN=max)`

Then only keeping households with a maximum age above 60.

`base <- subset(base, maxage >= 60)`

Or you could combine the two lines into one.  With the column names in your linked data:

```
> base <- subset(base, ave(base$datos.EDAD, base$datos.ID_VIV, FUN=max) >= 60)
> head(base)
   datos.ID_VIV datos.ID_PERSONA datos.EDAD datos.CONACT
21  10010000007    1001000000701         69           32
22  10010000008    1001000000803         83           33
23  10010000008    1001000000802         47           33
24  10010000008    1001000000801         47           10
36  10010000012    1001000001204          4           NA
37  10010000012    1001000001203          2           NA
```

Comment: This was perfect! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, we can `group_by` `H_ID` and select houses where `any` `AGE` is greater than 60.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(H_ID) %>% filter(any(AGE > 60))
```

Similarly with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[any(AGE > 60)], H_ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of the houses with a tenant `Age > 60` we can `filter` and create a list of `distinct` `H_ID`s

```
house_list <- base %>%
  filter(AGE > 60) %>% 
  distinct(H_ID) %>%
  pull(H_ID)
```

Then we can `filter` the original dataframe based on that `house_list` to *remove* any households that **do not** have someone over the age of 60.

```
house_df <- base %>%
  filter(H_ID %in% house_list)
```

To then calculate the `CON` values we can `filter` out `NA` values in `CONACT`, `group_by(H_ID)` and `summarize` to find the number of individuals within each house that have a non-NA `CONACT` value.

```
CON_calcs <- house_df %>%
  filter(!is.na(CONACT)) %>% 
  group_by(H_ID) %>%
  summarize(Count = n())
```

And `join` that back into the `house_df` based on `H_ID` to include the newly calculated `CON` values, and I believe that should end with your desired result.

```
final_df <- left_join(house_df, CON_calcs, by = 'H_ID')
```

Comment: I added the data for testing